# Anaconda install on Mac Big Sur Python cannot be opened

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, macos-big-sur

I installed Anaconda.Navigator on my Mac running Big Sur and I can no longer use Jupiter Notebook to run python scripts. I get this error when I try to run any python:
`Python cannot be opened because of a problem.`  I get the following error report in the terminal when I type `Conda` I can see all help commands and when type in `python` I can see:

```
Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  4 2020, 02:22:02) 
[Clang 10.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
```

From the Anaconda GUI when I toggle to Extensions I can see all the extensions that have been installed.  Yet it seems like it is not pointing to the Library correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you, Walter

```
Process:               Python [2539]
Path:                /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:            Python
Version:               3.6.4 (3.6.4)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        python3.8 [2477]
Responsible:           Terminal [1628]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2020-12-17 16:39:56.176 -0500
OS Version:            macOS 11.1 (20C69)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        7C2E0B35-674C-29FA-38C4-F9201BE80A1C


Time Awake Since Boot: 810 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    DYLD, [0x1] Library missing

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  dyld: No shared cache present
Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
  Reason: image not found

Binary Images:
       0x100000000 -        0x100000fff +org.python.python (3.6.4 - 3.6.4) <E585A67D-C0DB-448A-2E74-422D61BDC1C1> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
    0x7fff6960c000 -     0x7fff696a7fff  dyld (832.7.1) <DEA51514-B4E8-3368-979B-89D0F8397ABC> /usr/lib/dyld

Model: MacBookPro14,1, BootROM 429.60.3.0.0, 2 processors, Dual-Core Intel Core i5, 2.3 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.43f10
Graphics: kHW_IntelIrisGraphics640Item, Intel Iris Plus Graphics 640, spdisplays_builtin
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, LPDDR3, 2133 MHz, 0x802C, 0x4D5435324C3531324D3332443250462D3039
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, LPDDR3, 2133 MHz, 0x802C, 0x4D5435324C3531324D3332443250462D3039
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x170), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.77.111.1 AirPortDriverBrcmNIC-1675.1)
Bluetooth: Version 8.0.2f9, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 41.4
```

Comment: If you look at your output, it's not pointing to the version of python you have linked in your PATH (`Python 3.8.5`), it's pointing to:

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python`
Do you have Python 3.6 installed in that library location?

Comment: How do I change the path location either within Anaconda or install Python to this location?

Comment: Anaconda advises against changing the path variable. Is your conda/pip/jupyter notebook command working from terminal? If not, try this method. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65514763/6713740

Answer (score 3):

It turned out that the old versions of python that I had installed were somehow interfering with the Anaconda install and Python 3.8 that it wanted to install. I deleted all the old versions found in the Python.framework folder including the folder. I did not touch the python2.7 that came installed with Mac's OS.  Then I did a clean install of Anaconda Individual. One final hiccup was that the kernel was not running when I tried to open Jupyter Notebook so I had to manually set the kernel path with this

python -m ipykernel install --user

I found this fix on GitHUb

https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2301

I hope this helps someone in the future.