# Upgrading to macOS Big Sur(11.6.7) causes zsh not to find conda

Tags: macos, conda, zsh

I just upgraded to macOS Big Sur(11.6.7) from a lower version of macOS Big Sur and I am running into this error `zsh: command not found: conda`.

I referred to other similar questions such as [Zsh: Conda/Pip installs command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31615322/zsh-conda-pip-installs-command-not-found) and [Mas OS Big Sur update - Python3 / conda / pip not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65120490/mas-os-big-sur-update-python3-conda-pip-not-found) but none of the answers solves my issue.

I already have a block to initialise conda within my `~/.zshrc`, which should solve this issue in the first place and I have always had it prior to upgrading so I am unsure what is causing this issue:

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/yravindranath/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/yravindranath/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/yravindranath/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Users/yravindranath/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

Comment: I'm skeptical about the inference to causality. I've done the exact same update with no issue (also using `zsh` as default shell). Was there anything else in the `.zshrc` that possibly crashed before getting to the Conda stuff?

Comment: Aside from whatever you put into your .zshrc, did you actually **verify** that the PATH is set correctly by the time you are invoking `conda`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling anaconda using `rm -rf ~/opt/anaconda3/` and reinstalling it fixes it. Not sure what was causing the issue in the first place.